# XML parameters?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have an issue (I think) with casting XML to C# objects in a SOAP service.
Given this XML snippet:

```
<Weasleys>
  <Child>
    <Name>Ron</Name>
    <Age>11</Age>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Name>Fred</Name>
    <Age>13</Age>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Name>George</Name>
    <Age>13</Age>
  </Child>
</Weasleys>
```

I have an object

```
public class Weasley
{
  public List<Child> Weasleys {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

My method (paraphrasing) is `GetPeople(Weasley input)`. This works (I am using SoapUI to test)

My question is, if I change the XML to this:

```
<Weasleys>
  <Child Name="Ron" Age="11" />
  <Child Name="Fred" Age="13" />
  <Child Name="George" Age="13" />
</Weasleys>
```

How do I change my object to accommodate it? (with the current object, I get 3 instances of `Child` with `Name` and `Age` being `null`).

N.B. The object and XML are parts of much larger wholes and the elements have been changed to protect the innocent :)

Comment: For reasons I won't bore you with, it has to be the Object that changes (sorry)

Comment: I have tried [XmlRoot("Child")]public class Child
{[XmlElement("Name")]
public string Name {get; set;}
[XmlElement("Age")}public string Age {get; set;}
} without any success

Comment: I forgot to add - there are 0 to many Child (hence List<Child>)

Comment: What SOAP framework are you using, or how are you doing the binding from XML to Objects?

Comment: WCF (if I understand what you are asking here) and I have not written any code to bind / cast / serialise. I have simply have a method "GetPeople"(above)  - I presume the "cast" is done "under the hood" by .NET

Comment: I'm not sure WCF deserializes attributes by default, at least not with a [DataContractsSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer): *The DataContractSerializer does not support the programming model used by the XmlSerializer and ASP.NET Web services. In particular, it does not support attributes like XmlElementAttribute and XmlAttributeAttribute. To enable support for this programming model, WCF must be switched to use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContractSerializer.*

Comment: OW! so, no way then?

Comment: There is a way, but you have to change the configuration for the serializer, as the last statement mentions in the comment above

Comment: Therein lies the issue, I suppose. I have no idea how to do that, As I said, I've not written anything to do this so, it must be doing it automatically. How do I "override" this default behaviour?

Comment: I think this may require the use of Custom Message Encoder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted
Changed the method to accept XmlNode[] allowed me to deal with it correctly

Such fun!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define Name and Age as XML attributes in this way:

```
public class Child
{
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
  public string Name {get; set;}
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Age")]
  public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi Valeriof, many thanks for this. Unfortunately, it does not work :( - the object still has three "Child" with both Name and Age null.

Comment: Are you saying that now you get the right layout (with Name and Age as attributes on the same xml element) but that their value is null? This could depend on some other reasons

Comment: Yes - when interrogated, the object is populated correctly but with NULL values for Age and Name

Comment: By correctly, I mean there are three of them :)

Comment: I think this doesn't work because the OP is using a [DataContractsSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer): *The DataContractSerializer does not support the programming model used by the XmlSerializer and ASP.NET Web services. In particular, it does not support attributes like XmlElementAttribute and XmlAttributeAttribute. To enable support for this programming model, WCF must be switched to use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContractSerializer.*